# FLEX: thickness of slider track

Tags: apache-flex

How can I make the slider track a bit thicker with CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the class SliderThumb.

```
    public class MyThumbClass extends SliderThumb {
    public function MyThumbClass() {
        super();
        this.width = 25;
    }
}
```